# play 2.0 how can i overwrite my views out of a (securesocial) module?

Tags: view, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I'm using the securesocial plugin and use it as a module.

So my Structure is like:

```
project
 |
 |--app
 |---|
 |---|--views/main.scala.html
 |--conf
 |--logs
 |--module
 |---|--securesocial
 |---|------|
 |---|------|--app
 |---|------|---|
 |---|------|---|--views/main.scala.html
 |---|------|---|--views/login.scala.html
```

My simple Question is, HOW can I overwrite the main.scala.html from my module/securesocial/app/views with my "main.scala.html"-view in my "app/views"-folder?!

I mean with "overwrite", that I can include the login view into the "@content"-variable of my main.scala.html, that normally would work like:

```
@main("My title test"){
    <p class="note">
        Try <em>guillaume@@sample.com</em> with <em>test123</em> as password.
    </p>
}
```

But with "@main" I can not access (and therefore overwrite) my "app/views/main.scala.html" out of the module folder.

Answer (score 2):

SecureSocial renders views using a plugin that you can customize The default implementation is DefaultTemplatesPlugin that you can replace with your own to change the generated html.

To create custom pages and emails:

1. Create a new directory under views to place the custom templates for SecureSocial.
2. Create a new plugin that implements the TemplatesPlugin trait and renders those templates.
3. Edit the play.plugins file and replace DefaultPluginsTemplate with your own class.

You can see what methods you need to implement by looking at the TemplatesPlugin trait or in the documentation page: http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it the exact package name for the view:

```
@views.html.main("My title test"){
  ...
}
```